# Does anyone know where the code for the magnet tool can be found? And/or if that functionality can be applied to data other than the price chart?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, technical-indicator

NEOPHYTE DISCLAIMER:
I am (very new to pine-script and have only MINImal C++ experience, btw) working on writing a script for a pretty unique method of TA, as far as I can tell (experience, and feedback from a couple handfuls of pro-traders). But it's a process... for me, to code this thing. I'm reading docs, looking into community scripts, writing my own script currently, taking a udemy class, and become active in some communities.

OBJECTIVE:
In the meantime I would make my life a lot easier if the magnet tool worked on indicators/ in panes other than the price chart. Specifically on an RSI stepline. And the use case is to 'snap' the coordinates for a rey-type line to values of the RSI.

[eventually this process of drawing reys will be done automatically, using the rsi data corresponding to bar-index values from the label-array of a zig-zag higher-high-lower-low indicator (I IMAGINE this is how I'll pull it off, but really I'm just starting to assemble this thing mentally, as I begin to learn pine-script, hence the reason I am not yet attempting to ask in these terms, that I barely understand as of this moment.]

WHAT I TRIED AND THE RESULTS:
I've done my best job of looking at pine script docs, and searching online, and I have not found much information, at all. Pretty much just the description of the magnet tool, and how to use it..

I have asked in the pine script discord, so far nothing. And looking on reddit and searching the stack overflow forums for "magnet tool" brought up zero results. And no evidence so far that it's been tried elsewhere in trading view community scripts.

Any technical help, or even just a direction to some resources is very appreciated. I'm taking a class on pine script right now, and I am learning and making progress. But at this point, I admit that I do not know very much at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the tools on Tradingview are written in pinescript. Magnet tool is one of them and you can have this functionality in your pine script.

You can create a support ticket for your request -magnet tool working on other charts too.